# What is the difference between the Commodore 1701 and the 1702?

Tags: crt-monitor, commodore

Among the monitors offered by Commodore were the 1701 and the 1702, which, to my recollection, looked pretty much identical.  Were there any cosmetic, functional, or other differences between the two?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The 1701 and 1702 are virtually identical. They have the same specs, tube, inputs, casing, and manufacturer. The only real difference is the 1701 is older (1982 to early '83, 1702 is late '83) and the fact that the 1701 shipped with a 5-pin composite video cable instead of an 8-pin luma-chroma cable in the box (both monitors support both inputs).

A full list of the different Commodore monitor model specs can be found at Gona & Guru's excellent [Commodore Monitors by Model Number](https://gona.mactar.hu/Commodore/monitor/Commodore_monitors_by_model_number.html) web page.

Answer (score 1):

The 1701/1702 monitors appear to be identical. They share the same Brown Commodore-64 colored case. They both have dual inputs with a switch in back to select between them. However, these monitors could not be more different internally. The 1701 is heavier than the 1702, they use different tubes, and have different motherboards. The 1701 also has shielding and emissions issues which restricted its sale in Europe.

Comment: The accepted answer mentions that they have the same tube. Can you provide a source to help determine who is right?

Comment: @Tommy: A number of Commodore products exist in multiple variants with the same model number.  I would expect that there exist 1701 monitors and 1702 monitors that use identical tubes, but some monitors with different tubes share one or both model numbers.

Comment: Conveniently, Commodore provided a single service manual for both monitors — https://archive.org/details/manualzz-id-1127979 — and although there is only one set of circuit diagrams, there are two sets of schematics and two parts lists, one for the 1701 and one for the 1702. So ‘could not be more different’ is hyperbolic but there seem to be facts behind this answer.